# how to find hostname of all connected computer in my network with python programming?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I can find all the IP-addresses of computers connected to my network but i want to find host-name of that computer.Following line can give host-name of my PC because "192.168.43.253" is my IP. But,when i try to do same task with another IP-address which is connected to my network, i can not get host-name of that another IP-address. I am using python library called "nmap" to get the list of all connected IP in my network.

```
hostname=socket.gethostbyaddr('192.168.43.253')
```

Comment: nmap scan result can give you the hostname of scanned hosts. besides when using socket.gethostbyaddr what does it return?

Comment: This is python library function.name of library is "socket".it will return me my hostname.